# Have there been successful attempts at using a computer's heat to warm something up?

Tags: electrical-engineering, heat-transfer, heating-systems, computer, computer-hardware

Computers get hot.  So usually we try to make them less hot.  But what if instead of trying to cool down a computer we used that heat for something else?  Not necessarily any thing big like a whole room; maybe just something like a pet's cage.

**Is funneling the heat generated by a computer (any kind; desktop, server rack, etc.) a practical thing to do?  Are there any reliable stories of it being done successfully?**

Comment: You might want to read [Harvesting thermoelectric energy from computer graphics cards](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/372/harvesting-thermoelectric-energy-from-computer-graphics-cards)

Comment: Recently, Dutch start-up [Nerdalize](http://www.nerdalize.com/) has started offering e-radiators which are simply servers for heating up homes.

Comment: [Thermoelectric Technology to Harvest Energy from Internal Combustions Engines](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/389/7083) is also I think is similar

Comment: I mean, on a small scale I personally use my computer to heat up my basement.  I leave it running foldit@home all night during the winter and it pumps ~800watts of heat into the room all night long.  Cost as much to run as a radiator and benefits medical science.

Answer (score 1):

This makes little sense to do on the scale of a single computer that may draw 100 W.

However, this has been done on the scale of whole buildings.  Buildings that are designed expecting high power dissipation in some rooms but not others often have air conditioners or heat pumps for cooling/heating individual rooms or small zones.  These tie to building-wide water circulation systems.

The heat pumps that heat/cool individual rooms or zones take/dump the pumped heat from/to water circulating to a central pool.  A building-wide system keeps this pool in a controlled temperature range.  When the building needs overall heat, then the heat added to the pool from those zones that are being cooled reduces the deliberate heat that is added to the pool by the central system.  So yes, in that case the heat from computers, and anything else that dissipates power, is re-used to warm other parts of the building.